# R: Error when installing archived package manually

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install an archived R package, SciencesPo, but it's not installing, even after installing the dependencies. The following is the code and the messages that follow

> install.packages("C:\Users\Overman\Downloads\SciencesPo_1.4.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
>
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Overman/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> * installing *source* package 'SciencesPo' ...
>
> ** package 'SciencesPo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SciencesPo'
>
> * removing 'C:/Users/Overman/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/SciencesPo'
>
> In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘C:/Users/Overman/Downloads/SciencesPo_1.4.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: looks like you may need to install [`rtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Comment: @user20650 thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Installing Rtools solved the problem.